# tesorflow sort using top_k and any way

Tags: tensorflow

I'm tensorflow beginner.I want to know how to sort the list.

For example
[['s1',1],['s2',3],['s3',2]] <--from this list
Can I sort the first index in each list and get the zeroth index value in the sorted list?

[['s1',1],['s3',2],['s2',3]]

print In turn
sess.run(...) #'s1,s3,s2'

★★★

> s_name and number are tensor.
>
> s_name=tf.constant(,dtype=tf.string) # Read from csv file.
>
> number=The value was obtained using placeholder

## try:

i used 'dic'

```
dic={}
dic[s_name]=number (number=1,2,3)
```

print dic

```
{1:"s1",3:"s2",2:"s3"}
```

and i used 'top_k'

```
dic_key=dic.keys()

sort_distance=tf.nn.top_k(dic_key, k=3,sorted=True).values
reverse_distance=tf.reverse(sort_distance,axis=[0])

session.run(reverse_distance) #print '1,2,3'
```

This will sort the numbers, but I do not know how to get the s_name corresponding to a number.

Is there any way?
It is not necessarily a list.
Each `s_name` has a number. I want to sort by numbers and get s_name with sorted numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.nn.top_k` returns both the sorted values and the indices to sort the values; So you can firstly obtain the indices by sorting the *numbers*, combined with `tf.gather` you can then reorder the *s_name*:

```
lst = [['s1',1],['s2',3],['s3',2]]
```

1) Split `s_names` and `numbers` in separate lists but keep the order

```
s_names, numbers = zip(*lst)
```

2) Sort the numbers with `top_k` and retrieve the indices

```
indices = tf.nn.top_k(numbers, k=len(numbers)).indices
```

3) Use the indices to reorder `s_names`

```
s_names_sorted = tf.gather(s_names, indices[::-1])
```

Session run gives:

```
sess.run(s_names_sorted)
Out[18]:
array([b's1', b's3', b's2'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: top_n seems to be doing some kind of nearest-neighbors search. Not sure if it is exhaustive, approximate, or what distance function is being used. Perhaps it's exhaustive and cosine distance. Those are common. Then again the L2 norm is common as well for distances. The docs did not say when I checked it. :P Maybe Jaccard distance, who knows.